# Actualizar columna en funcion a los datos de otra columna de una misma tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos que lleva la cuenta del material que se ingresa y se egresa, haciendo la resta de lo ingresado menos lo egresado el resultado es el stock actual que hay de `"X"` producto.

```
UPDATE `stock de materias primas` SET `Unidades netas` = 
(SELECT `Ingresados en unidades` FROM `stock de materias primas` WHERE Codigo = 
(SELECT `Codigo` FROM `stock de materias primas`)) - 
(SELECT `Egresados en unidades` FROM `stock de materias primas` WHERE Codigo = 
(SELECT `Codigo` FROM `stock de materias primas`));
```

> Estructura de datos de la tabla

[image: Estructura de datos.]

esto me trae un claro error diciéndome que el problema esta en que no le estoy asignando un `target` al cual actualizar, realice una busqueda en foros y documentacion de Sql y por lo que entendi se debe conseguir el ID pero no consigo dar con la manera correcta.

Siempre hice consultas y manipulación de datos desde el programa con `C#` pero al ser una mala practica estoy intentando crear procedimientos y funciones en la base de datos y como aca no puedo recorrer con un `for` código por código no entiendo la forma que `Sql` comprenda que lo que requiero es que actualice cada y uno de los datos en funciones de la resta de ingresos con los egresos. 
Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro.

Comment: Cual es la estructura de las tablas que comentas? Deberias añadir la estructura en la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ahí colgue la imagen.

Comment: En principio, a primera vista, el cálculo que necesitas se puede hacer en la propia consulta `SELECT` sin necesidad de modificar el esquema de la tabla. La edición, para todos los registros, sería tan sencillo como: **UPDATE `stock de materias primas` SET `Unidades netas` = `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades`**. La consulta sería **SELECT *, `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades` AS `Unidades netas` FROM `stock de materias primas`**. PD: Las comillas invertidas me están matando el comentario xD

Comment: Ingresados en unidades y Egresados en unidades son valores variables, a su vez se debe calcular en la columna Neto de kilogramos y unidades esto es algo que se actualizara periodicamente. la pregunta es como logro obtener el codigo para el Where de la query, ya que son 1800 codigos y la idea es automatizarlo. ¿Me explique bien?

Comment: La pregunta más importante es: ¿es mejor para tu aplicación que ese campo esté actualizado instantáneamente o puede quedarse sin actualizar horas o días hasta que ejecutes tu consulta de actualización? Lo digo porque hay una tercera solución basada en vistas que quizá te sea también de utilidad.

Comment: El procedimiento se ejecuta en el mismo momento que se hace el SELECT a la tabla. con esto estoy satisfecho, gracias.

Comment: Bueno, si no quieres mejorar esta tabla, al menos te mando un enlace para que las siguientes que hagas sean un poco mejores: [Normalización de bases de datos (Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos). Échale un vistazo, en cuanto entiendas y apliques las primeras tres formas normales (puedes buscar otros tutoriales, quizá la wikipedia sea demasiado técnica) te darás cuenta de lo que haces mal en esta tabla. Un saludo y ¡suerte en tus proyectos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal lo que buscas, la consulta que necesitas es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE `stock de materias primas` S1 SET `Unidades netas` = 
    (SELECT `Ingresados en unidades` FROM `stock de materias primas` S2 WHERE S2.Codigo = S1.Codigo) - 
    (SELECT `Egresados en unidades` FROM `stock de materias primas` S3 WHERE S3.Codigo = S1.Codigo)
```

Que biene siendo lo mismo que ha comentado @OscarGarcia:

```
UPDATE `stock de materias primas` SET `Unidades netas` = `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades`
```

De esta manera te actualiza el valor `Unidades netas` con la resta de `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades` de la línea del código.

Comment: Has editado tu respuesta con el contenido de mi comentario `u_u"` "gracias" por el agradecimiento.

Comment: @OscarGarcia He puesto mi respuesta, y la consulta era mas larga (basicamente hacia un select a la misma tabla comparando los 2 códigos, con el mismo resultado, y despues he visto que se podia optimizar) lo pongo como antes y lo aclaro

Comment: @OscarGarcia Ha sido automatico, deberia haber puesto tu referencia al comentario, si te fijas es lo mismo lo unico que segui la logica del user y despues me di cuenta de que se podia simplificar. Siento el malentendido pero no era plagio lo mio

Answer (score 4):

El cálculo que necesitas se puede hacer en la propia consulta `SELECT` sin necesidad de modificar el esquema de la tabla ni del campo `Unidades netas`:

```
SELECT
  *,
  `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades` AS `Unidades netas`
FROM `stock de materias primas`
```

La edición para todos los registros, si quieres hacerla de todos modos, sería tan sencillo como:

```
UPDATE `stock de materias primas`
  SET `Unidades netas` = `Ingresados en unidades` - `Egresados en unidades`
```